# Can you use Telegram Inline keyboards in media groups?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am reading the documentation, and while .sendMessage() method has reply_markup argument, where you can pass the inline keyboard, media group (album, few files together, etc) doesn't have such an argument.

```py
# example with python-telegram-bot libriary
updater = Updater("token")
button = InlineKeyboardButton("this is a button.", callback_data="woo!")

# this works
updater.bot.sendPhoto("https://google.com/cat.png", reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[button]]))

# but this doesn't 
updater.bot.sendMediaGroup(InputMediaPhoto("https://google.com/cat.png"), reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup([[button]]))
```

Just wanted to make sure that this is actually true, since every other type of message CAN have an inline keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Media groups can't have a reply markup. Neither the `send_media_group` method nor the `InputMedia*` classes (which is the correct input type for the `media` argument of `send_media_group`) have a corresponding argument.

Please see the docs of

- `send_media_group`: [PTB](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_media_group) [Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup)
- `InputMediaPhoto`: [PTB](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inputmediaphoto.html) [Telegram](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto)

and [PTBs wiki entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#posting-files) on sending media groups.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Fixed the InputMedia* mistake in the example. Thanks!